# Display text side by side

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello I have the following code:

```js
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {
  display: none;
}

#hero h1 {
 margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: transparent;
   background: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2492815.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id = "hero">
<h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Sample
  <div class="quotes">
    <h1> Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="quotes">
    <h1> Change</h1>
  </div>
</h1>
</section>
```

The only problem is that the text is aligned on different lines, I want the text to be on the same line or beside each other with some margin in between. How can I fix that?

Also, how can I make it so the text stops alternating when it reaches the word `change`? Basically, it should only alternate between the text **once** and just stop at the word `change`

Comment: Learn about the `display` property. Or any other way of laying things out with CSS. (flexbox, grid, floats)

Comment: You can try putting the 2 divs with class of ''quotes'' in one container and making that container display:flex; or make the second ''quotes'' h1 into a span, or just nest it into a span.

Comment: @drinos, can you show please? Also, there is one more thing I want to do. Please see my updated post

Comment: @user2345, I haven't actually used jQuery before (if that even is jQuery), perhaps you can try adding a return; at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {
  display: none;
}

#hero h1 {
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: transparent;
   background: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2492815.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id = "hero">
<h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Sample
  <div class="quotes">
    <h1> Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="quotes">
    <h1> Change</h1>
  </div>
</h1>
</section>
```

Just add display: flex property to your h1 tag by default div's are block scoped so they occupy the whole row.

Comment: there is one more thing I would like to do. Please see my updated post

Comment: you can add an if condition to check if the quote is equal to 'change' and if it is just return the function.

Comment: can you quickly show pleasE?